# Google Custom search - force to not index part of page

Tags: search, indexing

I would like to ask a question about Google Custom Search.
I have an advertisement web (I am not sure of the specification "advertisement web", I am not a native speaker - users are inserting some things they want to buy or sell). 
For searching on the web I use Google Custom Search and I am satisfied except one problem:

On every advertisement page (detail page of the advertisement) there is a list of similar advertisements and Google is indexing these advertisements, too.

For example: I am looking for "Ford Escort" and results of searching are: 
1. Ford Escort (the "true" advertisement)
2. Ford Escort (similar advertisement for Ford Focus) - I don't want this one to show in results.

What can I do?
Thank You very much.